# Where can i get offline jQuery 1.7 API dump

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am tired googling for jQuery 1.7 API documentation file. Someone please provide me a link, where i can get offline jQuery 1.7 api dump.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "API file"?

Comment: you mean the code? http://code.jQuery.com

Comment: @RobW: yes, I'd say he wants JSAPI

Comment: Yes... I need a single file so that i can carry a printed document..

Comment: @Smamatti That's the download button for the framework code. The OP is looking for human-readable documentation.

Comment: @Smamatti I hope you will read and understand the Question....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both [html](http://jqapi.com/jqapi-latest.zip) and [air](http://github.com/downloads/erikzaadi/jqapi/jQAPI-1.6.air?v=05182011) versions are available (assuming you really want jQAPI, jQuery's documentation)

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.. Everyday i go through your  your answers and learn jQuery.. I consider "genesis, Flex King, mu is too short,Rob" as my jQuery mentors.. Its true.. Because of you people i love stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

http://jqapi.com/ - JQAPI has download in HTML/AIR format

Windows HELP version [here](http://charupload.wordpress.com/2007/12/07/jquery-documentation-chm/) (old version though)